# Как изменить иконку .exe файла с помощью cx_Freeze скрипта

Tags: python, icon, cx-freeze

Я написал игру на питоне и pygame и скомпилировал с помощью библиотеки cx_Freeze
Теперь я хочу изменить иконку исполняемого файла.
Вот cx_Freeze код

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None

if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [Executable("main.py", base=base, targetName="PongGame_by_e_d_u_a_r_d.exe")]


packages = ["pygame"]

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'packages':packages,
    },
}

setup(
    name="PongGame_by_e_d_u_a_r_d",
    options=options,
    version="VERSION_NUMBER e.g. 0.1",
    description='pong game',
    executables=executables
)
```

Что сюда добавить для добавления иконки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте путь к файлу с иконкой в Executable:

```
executables = [Executable("main.py", base=base, targetName="PongGame_by_e_d_u_a_r_d.exe", icon="path/to/icon.ico")]
```